# How to re-factor my method which returns value and may throw exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, exception

I have this simple method which adds an object to my Elastic index:

```
protected async Task<CreateResponse> AddAsync<T>(T entity, string id)
    where T : class
{
    var entityId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : id;
    var createResponse = await ElasticClient.CreateAsync(entity, c => c
        .Index(_indexName)
        .Id(new Id(entityId)));
    if (createResponse.IsValid)
    {
        return createResponse;
    }

    HandleCreateResponseError<T>(entityId, _ => "Id", createResponse);
}
```

```
private void HandleCreateResponseError<T>(
    string propertyName,
    string id,
    CreateResponse createResponse)
    where T : class
{
    Logger.LogError(
        "An error occurred while adding {0} with {1} = {2}, see debug info: {DebugInformation}",
        typeof(T).Name,
        propertyName,
        id,
        createResponse.DebugInformation);
    ThrowElasticException(createResponse);
}

private static void ThrowElasticException(IResponse response)
{
    if (response.OriginalException != null)
    {
        throw response.OriginalException;
    }

    throw new ElasticsearchClientException(response.ServerError.Error.Reason);
}
```

So, you can see here that if `createResponse` is NOT valid, the exception will be 100% thrown. But, Visual Studio gives me a compilation error message which says `Return statement is missing`. How to re-factor my `AddAsync` method without adding `return createResponse;` after calling `HandleCreateResponseError`? Because I think such returning is so weird.

The only way to avoid this compilation error is to add `return createResponse` statement, but IMHO it looks weird, since I'm returing a value which won't be returned due to a thrown exception.

Comment: Negate the If, put your handling code inside, return after the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply invert the `if`:

```
if (!createResponse.IsValid)
{
    HandleCreateResponseError<T>(entityId, _ => "Id", createResponse);
}

return createResponse;
```

That fixes the immediate error. Now *you* know that after `HandleCreateResponseError()`, the code won't continue. You can help the analyzer by marking the method `[DoesNotReturn]`:

```
[DoesNotReturn]
private static void ThrowElasticException(IResponse response) { ... }
```

That won't influence the compiler rule that a nonvoid method must return something, but it'll help in control flow analysis.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Somehow forgot about inverting ```if```. I'll accept your answer after SO allows me to do that. Still, why that inverting was needed at all? I mean, compiler can't go forward to see that an exception will be 100% thrown?

Comment: No, because then the compiler builders will have to solve the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem.